# Azure FCM NotificationHubClient Configuration for Data Payload?

Tags: json, azure, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub, payload

Using

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName, enableTestSend);
NotificationOutcome outcome = await hub.SendDirectNotificationAsync(fcmNotification, deviceUri);
```

I am able to send and receive notifications using FCM via the Azure hub to a Xamarin Android app, finally. However the payload is not present in the received RemoteMessage even though the sent fcmNotification json payload looks good and passes validation. I am basically looking at the RemoteMessage.Data property, but not finding the expected payload array. Looking at RemoteMessage structure, I haven't found any part of the payload array either.

I know that the Azure hub manipulates the notification by adding the necessary headers like content type, e.g. "application/json". Are there any other settings that are needed to be passed to enable the "data" only payload?

Comment: Could you share an example of the payload you are sending? It'd be good to see the schema.

One particular caveat about the way NotificationHubs works is that it's set up to be compatible with the _legacy_ FCM APIs, in order to be backward compatible with all the customers that still use the GCM schema. Here are the FCM docs on what that looks like: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: I am using hub.SendDirectNotificationAsync(fcmNotification, deviceUri) where the fcmNotification has the following properties:

    Content Type:  application/json
    Platform Type: fcm
    Body: {\"T\":\"PID\",\"O\":\"ABC\",\"I\":\"54*****69\",\"IU\":\"Test\",\"RI\":\"20032518185600003\",\"RD\":\"3/25/2020 6:18:56 PM\"

Answer (score 0):

Additional settings are not necessary, but the format of the entire notification contents has to have this type of structure:

"{ \"data\":{ \"A\": \"aaa\",\"B\": \"bbb\",\"C\": \"ccc\",\"D\": \"ddd\",\"E\": \"eee\",\"F\": \"fff\"}}"

The number of data elements is up to you. The data element name can be anything as well as the associated content except for the need for backslash usage for special characters. Both the element name and content can be inserted using variables creating a traditional composite string.

What is especially important is the inserted spaces as shown. Also note that traditional Json formatting is not acceptable because of the need for those spaces.

Comment: Where on earth is this documented and how did you figure it out?

Comment: I didn't ever find any documentation. I just keep manipulating the contents and stumbled onto the solution.

Comment: I played around with it a bit and standard serializers seem to work now but it does have to follow your structure.  Whitespace doesn’t seem to be an issue anymore.